# Why am I warned about not properly ejecting a disc every time I open my computer?

Tags: mac

For the past week, each time I open the computer in the morning, there is a notice saying I didn't properly eject the disc.  I have not had any disc, camera, or any other appliance plugged into the computer, so why the warning?

Comment: what about an SD card?

Comment: Can you make a screenshot? What Mac do you have? What kind of devices are connected into the computer? Do you have a SuperDrive? What version of OS X are you running? Please add more details here....

Comment: The name of the disc/disk is usually given which should help you determine the cause. Check the name of the unmounted volume.

Comment: To be honest this is how your question appear to us: You have a car and it is broken. You do not know if it is a diesel or gas? We need some fundamental information please. What computer, what operating system, does anyone else has access to your computer and has played with it, so as much information as you can provide.

Comment: It is a Mac desktop. OSX version 10.7.5 with 2.7 Ghz Intel Core i5.  None of which makes a difference to the problem.  No one else uses the machine. No discs, cards, super drives,etc have been used,  yet every morning for the past two weeks the machine tells me I "haven't properly ejected the disc".  There was no disc (or anything else) that needed to be ejected.